# How to define model architecture using keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I want to create neural network model as shown in figure below

[image]

and my x_train variable has (20204,2) dimensions and y_train has (20204,) dimensions

I am using keras Sequential model but when I run the code below

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(output_dim = 2, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim=20204))
model.add(Dense(output_dim = 3,init = 'uniform',activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer = 'adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=12,epochs=14)
loss_and_metrics = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=12)
print(loss_and_metrics)
```

I get an error saying

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_26_input to have shape (20204,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `Dense(units=4, kernel_initializer='random_uniform', activation = 'relu', input_shape=(2,))` for example. It seems that you use old api.

Comment: The `input_dim` refers to the dimension of input features which is 2 in your problem. Further, according to the figure, the hidden layer has 4 units, therefore `output_dim`  of first Dense layer must be 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say your input has a shape of `(20204, 2)`, you mean that you have *20204* training examples, each having *2* dimensions.

You need to tell your input to expect *2* dimensions and **not** *20204*. The error occurs because your model expects to receive *20204* features (i.e. parameter `input_dim=20204`) but actually receives *2* features.

To fix this, just change the parameter I mentioned above:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(output_dim=2, init='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=2))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=3, init='uniform', activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=12, epochs=14)
loss_and_metrics = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=12)
print(loss_and_metrics)
```

---

Edit:

As correctly pointed out by @today and @desertnaut, your figure shows the hidden layer having *4* neurons, not *2* like the code above would produce.

To change this you need to replace the parameter `output_dim=2` in your hidden layer with `output_dim=4`:

```
model.add(Dense(output_dim=4, init='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=2))
```

Comment: Furthermore, as @today correctly points out in the comments, the first dense layer should have `output_dim=4` and not 2.

Comment: @desertnaut I didn't notice the figure. I edited my answer to include this. Thanks for pointing that out!